# Custom metadata type Field Definition Data Type evaluating incorrectly in validation rule

Tags: validation-rule, custom-metadata, fielddefinition

A custom metadata type has a Field Definition related to an Entity. The following validation rule ensures the value of this field can only be a User lookup:

```
AND(
FieldDefinition__c != NULL,
FieldDefinition__r.DataType != 'Lookup(User)')
```

When trying to create a record with Field Definition set to a User lookup field the validation rule causes an error - incorrectly.

However, the following Apex block passes - correctly:

```
Custom__mdt m = [SELECT FieldDefinition__r.DataType FROM Custom__mdt WHERE Id = 'm003h0000011eBi'];

System.assertEquals(false,
    m.FieldDefinition__c != null &&
    m.FieldDefinition__r.DataType != 'Lookup(User)');
```

Is this yet another bug with custom metadata types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah dang, you're right.

So the Formula Context that Validation Rules for custom metadata record saves is...a bit weird. And indeed, as I look at it, the DataType we process in the Formula context is not the same information as what goes through the SOQL engine. Specifically, we don't include what the *target* of the relationship is (e.g. the `(User)` part).

To get you a known issue, you'll need to file a case. Once you have a case number, comment here and we'll get it fast tracked direct to engineering.

signed,
a member of the custom platform team :)

Comment: Thanks for confirming. Just logged the case thru partner community: 27676712